# Error while creating DynamoDB table using another existing table's structure in python using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am using code below for creating new DynamoDB  table.

```
import boto3
import os

dynamoclient = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='eu-west-1',
    aws_access_key_id='ACCESS_KEY_SOURCE',
    aws_secret_access_key='SECRET_KEY_SOURCE')
dynamoresource = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='eu-west-1',
    aws_access_key_id='ACCESS_KEY_SOURCE',
    aws_secret_access_key='SECRET_KEY_SOURCE')

dynamotargetclient = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-1',
    aws_access_key_id='ACCESS_KEY_TARGET',
    aws_secret_access_key='SECRET_KEY_TARGET')

curr_table=dynamoresource.Table('geo-test')


table = dynamotargetclient.create_table(
        TableName='geo-test-1',
        KeySchema=curr_table.key_schema,
        AttributeDefinitions=curr_table.attribute_definitions,
        
        ProvisionedThroughput={
            'ReadCapacityUnits': 5,
            'WriteCapacityUnits': 5
        })
```

So basically , I am creating a table and copying items in some other AWS account from my AWS account.
but, I am getting error while creating one.

ERROR below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 316, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 635, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateTable operation: One or more parameter values were invalid: Number of attributes in KeySchema does not exactly match number of attributes defined in AttributeDefinitions
```

Description of table 'geo-test' down below.

```
{'Table': {'AttributeDefinitions': [{'AttributeName': 'geohash', 'AttributeType': 'N'}, {'AttributeName': 'hashKey', 'AttributeType': 'N'}, {'AttributeName': 'rangeKey', 'AttributeType': 'S'}], 'TableName': 'geo-test', 'KeySchema': [{'AttributeName': 'hashKey', 'KeyType': 'HASH'}, {'AttributeName': 'rangeKey', 'KeyType': 'RANGE'}], 'TableStatus': 'ACTIVE', 'CreationDateTime': datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 7, 11, 16, 23, 460000, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'ProvisionedThroughput': {'NumberOfDecreasesToday': 0, 'ReadCapacityUnits': 10, 'WriteCapacityUnits': 5}, 'TableSizeBytes': 1104, 'ItemCount': 6, 'TableArn': 'arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:498526653762:table/geo-test', 'TableId': '4946225b-6342-41b9-bac0-9b27e9e17cad', 'LocalSecondaryIndexes': [{'IndexName': 'geohash-index', 'KeySchema': [{'AttributeName': 'hashKey', 'KeyType': 'HASH'}, {'AttributeName': 'geohash', 'KeyType': 'RANGE'}], 'Projection': {'ProjectionType': 'ALL'}, 'IndexSizeBytes': 1104, 'ItemCount': 6, 'IndexArn': 'arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:498526653762:table/geo-test/index/geohash-index'}]}, 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'V93HT96RDPP2NETR5RAAV2HQO3VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'server': 'Server', 'date': 'Tue, 23 Jun 2020 05:22:07 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.0', 'content-length': '943', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amzn-requestid': 'V93HT96RDPP2NETR5RAAV2HQO3VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG', 'x-amz-crc32': '3098259971'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

Same code is working for another table, which does not have LSI in it.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks !!!

Comment: What you can do is remove all AttributeDefinitions that are not present in KeySchema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a [github repository](https://github.com/ceb10n/dynamodb-table-copy) with a script that I used some time ago to copy a dynamodb table from one account to another. The code is written in portuguese, so I don't know if it will help. But to solve this particular problem, what you can do is:

```
table = dynamodb_client.describe_table(TableName="table_name")

attrs = []
keys = []

for k in table['Table']['KeySchema']:
    keys.append(k['AttributeName'])

for attr in table['Table']['AttributeDefinitions']:
    if attr['AttributeName'] in keys:
        attrs.append(attr)


dynamodb_client.create_table(
    KeySchema=table['Table']['KeySchema'],
    AttributeDefinitions=attrs,
    other-options-here)
```

Comment: Hey @RafaelMarques , I actually found the solution of this problem but I am not been able  to provide Local secendary index details. So, right now I have hard coded it, but is there any way , so that I can create LSI if my source table is having LSI ?